# Return in json more than one result from query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

can someone tell me how Can I response from this query, count() and list of products in one result??

Because at this moment its only return me Array with limit, i want count() without limit, of all products:

Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]

```
router.get('/products', function (req, res) {

  var size = parseInt(req.query.pageSize);

  if (req.query.pageNumber == 1) {
    var page = 0;
  } else {
    var page = parseInt(req.query.pageNumber) * req.query.pageSize - req.query.pageSize;
  }

  Product.count()
    .exec(function (err, products) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(404).json({
          message: 'Can not download this list'
        })
      } else {
        Product.find().skip(page).limit(size)
          .exec(function (err, products) {
            if (err) {
              res.status(404).json({
                message: 'Can not download this list'
              })
            } else {
              res.json(products);
            }
          })
      }
    })
});
```

Comment: This **is** how you do it. It's always been the way you do it with every database engine. You cannot include the total count within a "page" of results without doing something really silly, and trying to squash the entire result set into a single document. That breaks the BSON limit in real cases with MongoDB. You can use promises to clean up the nesting. But your basic output should be instead: `res.json({ "count": count, "products": products })` and then you're done.

Comment: do you mean you want total nos of documents from db and the limited document in response

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in this way :

```
res.json({ "key1": value1, "key2": value2})
```